# Does inner WillPopScope widget handle the pop event first or does the outer one?

Tags: flutter

I have 2 nested `WillPopScope` widgets. When the app first launches, the outer one handles the pop events first, then the inner one. But after a change such as calling `setState` or hot reloading, the inner one handles the pop event first. This inconsistency breaks my app's behavior. Is this a framework problem or am I missing something?

Below is the working code (without irrelevant details):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            print('outer');
            return true;
          },
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
    print("inner");
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: onWillPop,
      child: const Center(child: Text("1")),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But why do you need two `WillPopScope` when all you're doing is displaying them on the same screen?

Comment: @iDecode the inner one is a part of a library, the outer one is a part of an app that uses that library. This is an oversimplification.